# Is it possible to using or in codeigniter form validation?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an input which can be decimal or numeric. I want to use this rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'decimal|numeric');
```

But i think the rules in form_validation helper not working with "or" statement. If the price is something like that "149.99" it's valid but if the price is "150" it's not.

Am i missing something or isn't it possible to use something like that:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'decimal or numeric');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CI, does not allow to mix datatypes when validating. Instead, Create your custom validation rule.

Declare a rule like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'callback_decimal_numeric');
```

After create a method on the controller

```
    public function decimal_numeric($str)
    {
        if ($str <isdecimal&nummeric>) //Use your logic to check here
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('decimal_numeric', 'The %s field validation has failed');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`The decimal rule requires a parameter to be passed`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference

Answer (score -1):

use (**required|decimal**) this 
example:
 `$this->form_validation->set_rules('lat', 'Latitude', 'required|decimal')`;